# Angular 4 application on Github Pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have a simple `Angular (4)` application which I want to host on `Github Pages`, the option to do this from `Angular CLI` seems removed. Is there a way to do this, if so how?

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "e-portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

When trying to use ng build I get this message

As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.

my debuglog

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.9.5
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Portfolio\ePortfolio\package.json'
4 verbose stack     at Error (native)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Portfolio\ePortfolio
6 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 error node v6.9.5
9 error npm  v3.10.10
10 error path C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Portfolio\ePortfolio\package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -4058
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Portfolio\ePortfolio\package.json'
15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Portfolio\ePortfolio\package.json'
15 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
15 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using this commad `ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY_NAME/"`

I switched out to my repository which is called ePortfolio, I typed it in as eportfolio, It seems that the letter P had to be capital for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: did that but all I see is the `loading...` from my `index.html`, not what I want to show

Comment: Is there any error on the console? A good way to the is using http-server on your dist folder to make sure it is a git hub pages.

Comment: A lot of these errors if I open the console in browser: `Failed ... to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, I'm not sure what you mean with dist folder, English is not my native language.

Comment: Okay first run ng build. If the process is okay it will generate a dist folder. The content of that folder is what actually is your compiled angular application which is what is sent to the server. To make sure your build version is working  install the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server and run the command http-server on the dist folder. Check if your applications wotks as expected. If it does build it like this ng build --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY_NAME/" and then run ngh on your main folder. That should work.

Comment: `ng build` worked on my desktop earlier, but on my laptop (which is all I have now) it says `You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.` but I am in my angular-cli project, npm start works. I don't see any `dist/` directory either I only see `e2e`, `src` and `node_modules`

Comment: try running npm install

Comment: I did npm install but this didn't change it, I added my package.json above if there is something in there.

Comment: Try doing the updating angular cli part from this repo https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: This took longer than expected, by upgrading my angular-cli I can ng build successfully. I followed your steps from up higher, does it matter from what branch of my Github project I do the ng build --href... + do I have to do this in my dist folder?

Comment: I think when you run the ngh command it automatically generates a gh-pages branch and pushes to that

Comment: Also make sure you enabled the GH pages hosting in the project settings

Comment: Check the gh-pages branc remove your jekyll theme and a no jekyll file https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I found is a 2 steps process. First of, you need to know that Github Pages doesn't handle well `base href` and so disabling the `pushState` and removing the `base href` was enough on my side to get going.

Here's the steps:

<s>1- remove the backslash `"/"` from the `base href` in your `index.html`</s>

```
<base href="">
```

2- Disable the `pushState` by adding the argument `{useHash: true}`. In my case, I have an `app-routing.module.ts` which I updated with following code:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})], // <-- HERE
   exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Then publish to a Github Page and we're in business

**EDIT**

Just doing step 2 is enough for it to work `{useHash: true}`